# .getDay() is not working while converting date to Particular timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is my code:

```js
var date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" });
var n = date.getDay();
```

Trying to convert data into IST.

without `.toLocaleString` `.getday` is working perfectly. But when used getting below error:

```
TypeError: date.getDay is not a function
    at Object. (D:\Learning\node-course\web-server\src\app.js:12:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200`enter code here`:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Is there any better way to convert date into IST and find the day as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDate()` instead. This method return today's date

Answer (score 0):

The return value from `toLocaleString` is a **string**. Strings don't have a `getDay` method.

JavaScript's `Date` object has no features letting you use other timezones. It only supports UTC and the current timezone where the code is running (simultaneously, by offering some methods that give you information in UTC and others that give you information in your local timezone). (There's [a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) that will fix that, but it's still only at Stage 2.)

If you want to know what day it is in the user's current timezone, just use `getDay` directly on your date object. If you want a different timezone, you'll need a well-maintained library that supports multiple timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Because its converted in to string, and string don't have `getDay()` function, You can try,

```js
var dateString = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata" });
var date = new Date(dateString);
var n = date.getDay();

console.log("Date String: ", dateString);
console.log("Day:", n);
```

Comment: Thanks @turivishal for the explanation and solution, it worked!